# How to set datasource connection pool size and other properties in Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are using default datasource connection pool HikariPool-1, and we want to configure datasource connection max connection pool size, initial size and other datasource properties.

We tried with following but it crash the application and server not start

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize = 120
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=20
```

or

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=20
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
```

We also tried with following, it allow to start server but there is no impact and pool size remain default 10

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=20
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
```

Comment: "Server not start" What error does it throw? Also, albeit unrelated: Are you sure you need a minimum of 20 connections? Have you read [HikariCP's recommendations on the matter](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing)?

Comment: It fails to make database connection and error in console related to that.